# How to add "dont show me again" checkbox to an alertbox?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When my android app starts there will be a prompt that asks user whether to upgrade to newer version or not.I used an alertbox to display it.I have two buttons in it, "Upgrade" and "No thanks".Then I  added a checkbox to it.And the label for that check box is "Dont ask me again". When user click on that checkbox,that should be remembered and the prompt shouldnt asked again.Can anyone suggest me a solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best option you can go for is of [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You can Save the in Internal Database.

```
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
        int currentVersion = info.versionCode;
        // version name here for display in the about box later.
        this.sVersionName = info.versionName;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int lastVersion = prefs.getInt("Key", 0);

        if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {

            prefs.edit().putInt("key",currentVersion).commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartUp.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)

           //  Your Code goes here if you want to Display it Only Once.

            return true;
        }
```

EDIT

```
SavePreferences("MEMORY1","Your String Here");   

private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(pref, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void LoadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings.pref, 0);
    String sDefault_Card = settings.getString("MEMORY1", "");
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me the code to save data to sharedpreference and  retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and save / retrieve boolean value to indicate checked / uncheked state

Answer (score 1):

You could use SharedPreferences to store user's selection:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());      
boolean showPrompt = preferences.getBoolean("Show_Prompt", true);
```

Comment: can you please provide me the code to save data to sharedpreference and  retrieve it?